# Shabbat songs that rhyme only with Hashem's real name

Tags: history, theology, shabbat-songs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pronouncing Hashem's name in a song](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11022/pronouncing-hashems-name-in-a-song)

Many songs we sing and the Shabbat table we use the word Hashem instead of Hashem's real name even when the song was written in rhyme or the tune clearly calls for the word Ado-ni as the clear word that rhymes. For example Tzur Mishelo. 
Where does this custom come from and why?

Comment: @Naftali I agree with [msh210 in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2874254#2874254) that while highly related, these two questions are not quite duplicates.

Comment: @IsaacMoses haha that is not up to u ^_^ that is up to the community.

Comment: @Naftali What am I, chopped liver? Last I checked, I'm a member of the community and entitled to express my opinion. (And BTW, while I generally wouldn't, I am, in fact, empowered to overrule the community if I disagree strongly with its action.)

Comment: @IsaacMoses do not dis chopped liver :-P You do not really have to state in the comments that it is not a duplicate. you can choose to vote or not to vote like everyone else ^_^

Comment: @Naftali, everyone else is entitled to express their reasoned opinion in comments, too. (I happen to be borrowing msh210's reasoning in this case.)

Comment: I'm voting duplicate because the other question already asks why they were put in explicitly if you shouldn't pronounce them. The proof this question brings from Tzur MiShelo is that they were actually explicit. I don't think that is such a significant addition to the question. I had already assumed they were originally explicit. Maybe the questioner can leave this proof as a comment to that question. [Edit: This was before I became a mod.]

Comment: Oops, didn't notice this had actually been closed before editing it...

Answer (score 1):

When I sing the song I **do** say Hashem's Name on 1st iteration.

That was how it was intended -- To glorify Hashem.

See here: [Pronouncing Hashem's name in a song](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11022/719)

Comment: Do you have a source for this practice?

Comment: @HachamGabriel haha I am my own source. my family has always done it. I am my own source. They are songs that were meant to be sung how they were written.

Comment: @HachamGabriel see update.

Comment: I have seen that stream but I just wanted you to add a source into your answer. +1

Comment: @HachamGabriel hehe I just had to search for that question... You could have just told me about it....

Comment: That is true. My bad

Answer (score 0):

Although it is the custom of many people to say Gd's name in songs, if you don't want to you can always add a  "K" sound to any of the names to both rhyme and avoid saying Gd's name.

If you have the custom to say "Hashem" in some song where it does not sound right, odds are there used to be a different tune, where it did sound correct.