# Why does the chazzan start ashrei in selichot earlier?

Tags: chazzan-prayer-leader, selichot

In the Artscroll prayer, the point at which the shaliach tzibbir begins reading [aloud](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83164/explain-the-use-of-the-chazzan-to-end-paragraphs) is marked by little dots. During the year, the Ashrei prayer has little dots [before](http://kb.artscroll.com/admin/media_store/2/AA-00558/photo%202.PNG) "tehillat hashem". But in the Selichot book, the dots are before "tzadik hashem b'chol d'rachav".

Is there a different selichot-relevant meaning or purpose to having the chazzan begin reading out loud at the earlier point?

Comment: I've never seen a chazzan actually do this but I have seen it in Artscroll

Comment: I assumed it's for Chazzanim who like to sing to have fancier introductions. There's obviously no Halakhic difference or need to say any of it aloud. @Heshy I've seen it with fancier Chazzanim

Comment: Ashrei during Shlichos????

Comment: Ashrei **before** selichos.

Comment: @Danny If I'm correct, the Yekke don't say _Ashrei_

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - we start Selichos with Adon Olom, in a haunting tune, appropriate for the spooky predawn hour.

Answer (score 5):

I'm vaguely recalling what I had heard many years ago when I studied *Nusach* at the Belz School of Jewish music (part of Yeshiva University.)

Cantor Beer taught the course on Selichot and he was (and still is) a maven on Tefillah history. He explained that beginning at *Tzaddik Hashem bechol Derachav* is a "recurring" theme for Selichot as well as the High holiday season. One of the fundamentals of Teshuva is admitting the concept that "G-d is correct and righteous and mankind is sinful." There are similar phrases scattered throughout various Selichot and other Tefillot, esp. on Yom Kippur.

Similarly, the next verse, *Karov Hashem Lechol Kor'av* - "G-d is near to all those that call to him" - is likewise an appropriate Selichot / High Holiday theme. We pray and hope that G-d listens to our prayers and pleas at this time of year and forgives us for our sins and helps us perform better to serve Him.

Comment: So wouldn't Ashrei during the aseret yemei t'shuva start with "malchutcha malchut..."?

Comment: @rosends One can speculate just about anything when it comes to *chazzanut*. Keep in mind that the original function of the *chazzan* is as Shat"z, which meant, originally, for Amidah, Torah reading, Kaddish, and a few other items. The idea of using him for ending paragraphs, I gather, was much later. As such, there is no "formality" on where that begins. Re - Selichot - I assume that some "standard" was established and kept. *Malchut* is not a prominent theme of Selichot. Not on the level as *teshuva* is. Also, *Malchut* is prominent on RH, far less prominent during 10 days Teshuva.