# Can you mezamen with people who aren’t bentching?

Tags: bentching

If you’re sitting 3 people and you all ate bread, you have to do zimun. Does it matter though if the other 2 people won’t be bentching (in other words they’re not so frum and don’t care about berachot). So are you allowed to do zimun, which is a summon to bentch, with people who aren’t even gonna bentch? Does the obligation of שלשה שאכלו כאחת חיבין לזמן still kick in?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "not so frum and don’t care about berachot"? 1) They disbelieve in the blessings or in HaShem (r"l), or 2) they typically don't care to observe the commandments or to recite blessings? The original traditional construction of a zimun involves only an individual m'zamein reciting the blessings and thereby exempting two or more attentive listeners of their obligation.

Comment: Indeed as Fred notes this is literally what's supposed to happen https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36588/759

Comment: Notably in such a case, the dispensation to not say everything out loud (if such a thing even exists) wouldn't apply since you need to help them fulfill their obligation.

Comment: @Fred not koferim, just they don’t particularly care to do some mitzvot. I know if they were koferim I wouldn’t even be able to do zimun with them

Comment: According to some opinions, someone who doesn’t care to do a Mitzvah that everyone does cannot be counted for a Zimun (see Mishnah Berurah on 199:3)